# How to set absolute number of lines for paragraph

Tags: paragraphs

*How can I set a paragraph to a certain absolute number of lines?*

## Desired outcome

### Case 1: Text length is shorter

Remaining space should be filled with blank lines

### Case 2: Text length is dead on

Nothing to do

### Case 3: Text length is longer

Following paragraph should start position at as if the text had exactly the specified length

## Example

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Let's say the text should be 5 lines long

\section{Short}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
\vspace{2\baselineskip}

Following paragraph

\section{Long}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
\vspace{-1\baselineskip}

Following paragraph
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** Or even better, throw an error if text is too long

Answer (score 1):

You can measure the paragraph's length. Some adjustments for keeping the current status of `\if@nobreak` and `\everypar` is necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{parlines}[1]{%
  \par
  \if@nobreak\def\kept@nobreak{\@nobreaktrue}\else\def\kept@nobreak{}\fi
  \edef\kept@everypar{\the\everypar}%
  \setbox0=\vbox{\BODY\@@par\xdef\parlinesprevgraf{\the\prevgraf}}%
  \kept@nobreak
  \everypar=\expandafter{\kept@everypar}%
  \ifnum\parlinesprevgraf>#1\relax
    ERROR, too long,\par\vspace{#1\baselineskip}%
  \else
    \BODY\par
    \vspace{\numexpr#1-\parlinesprevgraf\relax\baselineskip}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Let's say the text should be 5 lines long

\section{Short}
\begin{parlines}{5}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
\end{parlines}

Following paragraph

\section{Long}
\begin{parlines}{5}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
\end{parlines}

Following paragraph
\end{document}
```

[image]